# macOS-Resize many buttons with different width with Autolayout

Tags: macos, cocoa, autolayout

I have some buttons have same height and different width. And **every button's width might change with user's operation**.

I tried to use NSStackView and two views(help to make StackView in the centre of super view.They be set have equal width).It looks like this:

[image]

But this solution can not resize of width of each button, and **I hope I can set button frame size and have equal distribution spacing**

And I will draw text and image to these button rather than use setTitlt: to set button's title.

Have any idea？ Thanks

Comment: You're on the right track, but I suspect you need to look at the intrinsic size of the buttons. Most control views have an *intrinsic* size, which is the size the view wants to be. This then influences the content "hugging" and "compression-resistance" (CHCR) priorities; In other words, how hard does auto-layout will try to make each button wider, narrower, or exactly the size it wants to be. Try increasing the hugging and compression priorities and see how that affects your stack view. Also check the stack view properties, because it has CHCR priority overrides for its subviews.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by myself by adding constraint programmatical.

This is my solution:

1. Can not use 'Equal' as a constraint to restrict button's width. Recommend use 'Less or equal' to restrict button's maximum width.
2. Calculating all button maximum width that all button had maximum status.
3. Add an NSView near the first and last button (On the left and on the right) respectively.
4. Set NSView constraint to Left and Right space to the nearest neighbor is zero, width and height could ignore it. And set both of these NSView to have 'Equal Width'.
5. Embed all buttons to an NSStackView and set it height. [image]
6. Set 'Equal Height to Superview' constraint to all button. All buttons had same height with StackView and all buttons' width is same too.
7. In the code, you can add constraint when you want to resize button. Eg. `[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:item attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:0.0 constant:value];`